# PowerShell parameters - "The term 'param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Tags: variables, powershell, input, parameters

Consider:

```
notepad # Starts Notepad
Get-Process notepad # Finds the processes named notepad
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$ProcessID
) #This should request user input, and store it in a variable#
Stop-Process $ProcessID # Stops the input process ID#
```

When I try to run this, I'm met with:

```
param : The term 'param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:3 char:1
+ param(
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (param:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Stop-Process : Cannot bind parameter 'InputObject'. Cannot convert the "A" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Diagnostics.Process".
At line:6 char:14
+ Stop-Process $ProcessID
+              ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Stop-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopProcessCommand
```

I'm quite new to PowerShell, and I'm severely confused because of this at the moment. Either because I don't understand it, or because it's early in the morning.

Comment: `Param` needs to be at the beginning of your function or script, it can be after some comments, but before any other command.

Comment: Interesting.
Is there any way to give user input later on in the code? The final line relies on the string to function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your script requires arguments, the `Param` keyword must be the first statement in the script.

However, you can ask the user for input later by using the `Read-Host` cmdlet:

```
$processId = Read-Host "Enter the PID of the process to kill"
```

Answer (score 0):

The final result after removing the parameters and using the Read-Host cmdlet:

```
notepad
Get-Process notepad
$ProcessID = Read-Host "Enter the PID of the process to kill"
Stop-Process $ProcessID
```

It works flawlessly.